# Cannot seem to get map_marker_click to register I clicked in Shiny/Leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I want to build an interactive map allowing me to look at closely at facilities in particular districts using Shiny/Leaflet in R

The district is a user input (drop-down box), and facilities are shown if they user checks a box. All these work fine.

I want Leaflet/Shiny to draw polygons associated with the facility when I click on the marker representing that facility. But it seems like R isn't even registering my `input$map_marker_click` in my `observe` function.

so my `ui.r` code:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel(""),
    sidebarLayout(position = "right",
      sidebarPanel( selectInput("districtinput", "Select a district:",
                    list("Alfred Nzo")),
                    checkboxInput("addClinics", "Show Clinics", FALSE),
                    verbatimTextOutput("clickid",placeholder = TRUE)),
      mainPanel(leafletOutput("mymap"))
    )
  )
)
```

and my `server.r` code:

```
shinyServer(
  function(input,output,session){
      DMap<-reactive({
        data <- PlotAN
        if (input$districtinput=="Alfred Nzo"){data <- subset(PlotAN,"Alfred Nzo" %in% input$districtinput)}   
        return(data)
      })

      observe({
        if (input$addClinics){
          data<-clinics[clinics$district  %in%  input$districtinput]
          leafletProxy("mymap") %>% addMarkers(lat=data$lat, lng=data$lon, popup = data$clinic)
        }
       if (!input$addClinics){
         leafletProxy("mymap") %>% clearMarkers()
       }
      })

     observe({
       click<-input$map_marker_click
       print(click)
       if(!is.null(click$id)){
        text<-paste(click$id,": ",click$lat,";",click$lng)
        leafletProxy("mymap") %>% clearPopups() %>% showPopup(lat=click$lat,lng=click$lng,popup=text)
        output$clickid<-renderText({text})
       }
     })

    output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        addPolylines(data=DMap(),color = "black", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
                  opacity = 1.0, 
                  highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", weight = 2,
                                                      bringToFront = TRUE))     

    })    
  }
)
```

For now I haven't even yet linked it to the polygon data I want to show because I wanted to see what `input$map_marker_click` returns before deciding how I can use it to link back to my polygon data. But `input$map_marker_click` doesn't even register.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with all libraries needed to run your code.

Comment: @MLavoie Thanks for the quick response. Due to confidentiality, I cannot share everything but I have created a small data set which illustrates my problem with the above code. You can find it here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u9H55weFwJjfWftaAKdGqumMFbSve2A-

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `input$mymap_marker_click`. The first part is the mapId rather than just 'map', as you could have multiple maps in one app.

This pattern is true for accessing events on other widgets too, like datatables created with the DT package.